# Doctrine parent, child relationship hydration

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am having a problem and I am afraid I am missing something stupid. But I am struggling with searching for a similar problem to see what I am missing.

Anyway, I have a product entity:

```
<?php

class Product {
    private $productid;
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MyNamespace\CategoryBundle\Entity\Category")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="categoryid", referencedColumnName="categoryid")
     * })
     */
    private $category;

    public function getCategoryPath()
    {
        $category = $this->category;
        $items = array($category);

        var_dump($category->getParent());
        while (null !== $category->getParent()) {
            $category = $category->getParent();

            $items[] = $category;
        }

        return $items;
    }

}

class Category {
    private $categoryid;
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var \Category
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MyNamespace\CategoryBundle\Entity\Category")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parentid", referencedColumnName="categoryid")
     * })
     */
    private $parent;

    public function getParent()
    {
        return $this->parent;
    }
}

?>
```

And I try:

```
<?php
$product = $entityManager->find('MyNamespaceProductBundle:Product', 10);
$categories = $product->getCategoryPath();
?>
```

The problem is, that the categories array only contains the directly linked category. It doesn't seem that doctrine fetches the parent ones so $category->getParent() will always return null and if I look to the mysql-general log I don't see a query raised for the parent category.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just ran a test on your example. This works perfectly fine. No idea how your data looks like, is there a reference to a parent category in this specific case? Also not sure why added the categoryPath inside the Product class?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you should call the `getCategoryPath()` method inside the Category class like `getCategoryid()` and just return the `categoryid` value. Then:

```
<?php

$product = $entityManager->find( 'MyNamespaceProductBundle:Product', 10 );
$category = $product->getCategoryid();
$categoryProducts = $entityManager->find( 'MyNamespaceCategoryBundle:Product',array( 'categoryid' => '$category' ) );

?>
```

Comment: I am sorry, offcourse the method was already in the entity but I forgot to copy it. Thanks.

Comment: @ManoloSalsas In the example he's returning an array not a single id, he adds all the ids up to the last parent. But i agree the Category class should handle this, not the Product class.

Comment: Hi @ManoloSalsas I didn't work yet for me unfortunately but after some searching I found very nice bundle to have nested entities and it's also very performance-friendly. See: https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md